# How can you know which token was staked on your contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, metamask

I am creating a smart contract where users can stake any ERC20 tokens, but I need to know which token they have staked. Is there any way to do that? I cannot access the event logs from inside the contract and the transferFrom address does not seem to pass a token address in its parameters.

Since I also have access to the front, I was thinking I could use Metamask to retrieve the selected token address and pass it during the function call to the smart contract.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by  "take" as in "take any ERC20 tokens"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant stake. I have edited my question.